# Поиск и вывод значения в php

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет!
У меня есть переменная $one 
Как пример, данная переменная содержит в себе строку следующего вида

```
$one = "Первый раздел/Второй подраздел/Третий под-подраздел";
```

Сейчас я делаю из этой строки массив:

```
$two = explode('/', $one);
```

И получаю следующие:
Первый раздел,Второй подраздел,Третий под-подраздел
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно выполнить поиск в массиве по ключевому слову (к примеру, "подраздел"), что бы переменная $three возвращала исключительно "Второй подраздел"?
P.S.  При этом, значение "Второй раздел" не всегда будет являться $two[1];, т.к. оно может являться 2,3 или даже 4 значением в массиве.
Спасибо.

Comment: "Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне правильно " --- правильнее было бы создать изначально массив с нужным уровнем вложенности........а ещё дерево, где каждый лист ссылается на родителя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов реализации много, можно через `array_filter`, а можно вот так

```php
<?php
$data = [ 'Первый раздел', 'Второй подраздел', 'Третий под-подраздел'];

function searchDataValue( $data, $searchValue ) {
    $result = [];
    foreach( $data as $value ) {
        if ( mb_strpos( $value, $searchValue ) !== false ) {
            $result[] = $value;    
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$searchValue = " подраздел";

echo "Поиск \"".trim($searchValue)."\" среди ".count($data)." элементов...";
$found = searchDataValue( $data, $searchValue );
if ( count( $found ) > 0 ) {
    echo "\nнайдено совпадений - ".count($found)."\n";
    echo "А именно:\n";
    foreach( $found as $s ) {
        echo "- ".$s."\n";
    }
} else { echo "\nсовпадений не найдено."; }
```

Результат:

```
Поиск "подраздел" среди 3 элементов...
найдено совпадений - 1
А именно:
- Второй подраздел
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Это работает!